# C++ Modules - export extern "C" - How to wrap externally linked function in a Module

Tags: c++, module, clang, extern

So basically, I'm writing some WASM/C++ code. For that I'm mainly compiling with:

```
--target=wasm32-wasi -std=c++2a -flto ... -fmodules -fmodules-ts ...
        -mbulk-memory (enables memset/memcpy intrinsics)
```

Now with with no standard-library I told my compiler that there are some builtin functions/intrisics available - because of the -mbulk-memory flag. Like so:

```
// wasm.hpp
extern "C" void* memset(void* pMemory, i32 value, size_t size) noexcept;
extern "C" void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t count) noexcept;
```

I wanted to switch to C++ Modules and the only way to use these function is to either redeclare them in each cppm Module or leave the #include in the global module segment.

```
#include "wasm.h"
export module foo;
```

I thought It would me cool to also wrap that code in an importable module. But if I declare a Module:

```
export module wasm;
export extern "C" void* memset(void* pMemory, i32 value, size_t size) noexcept;
export extern "C" void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t count) noexcept;
```

the compiler doesn't complain, but the methods don't get exported. They are simply invisible ouside the module.
In some way, this makes sense, cause these functions really don't belong to any named module - since they are not implemented there.

I thought what I'm doing is allowed as it is explained here: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/31/modules-2.html

Answer (score 1):

the following seems to do what i want.
I can declare a extern "C" method in the global fragment and reexport it inside the module by prefixing "using ::"

```
extern "C" int foo();
export module mymodule;
export using ::foo;
```

I also tried if it is linkable, by implementing foo() in plain C adding it to my link step. Worked...
This should enable:

- Wrapping builtins in modules
- Wrapping external stuff from C oder wat/wasm files in a module